# How do I change the position of a view in a Linear Layout.?

Tags: android

So I have a Linear Layout already populated with children. Is there a way to change the position at which one of the children is located?

I'm trying to swap to views between them if that's of any help.

```
final LinearLayout parrent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llWidgetScreen);
    final LinearLayout Delailah = new LinearLayout(this);
    Delailah.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    AppWidgetHostView wedgy = attachWidget(mAppWidgetHost.createView(this, appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo));
    Delailah.addView(wedgy);
    final Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)(20*scale +0.5f), android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0f));
    btn.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            parrent.removeView(Delailah);
            return false;
        }
    });
    btn.setBackgroundColor(mainColor);
    btn.setText(parrent.getChildCount()+1+"");
    btn.setTextColor(textColor);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(ReadyForDrag==0)
            {
                btn.setBackgroundColor(actiColor);
                ReadyForDrag++;
                DragPosition1=Integer.parseInt(btn.getText().toString());
            }
            else if(ReadyForDrag==1)
            {
                btn.setBackgroundColor(actiColor);
                ReadyForDrag=0;
                LinearLayout v1 = (LinearLayout)parrent.getChildAt(DragPosition1);
                LinearLayout v2 = (LinearLayout)parrent.getChildAt(Integer.parseInt(btn.getText().toString()));
                //move view 2 to position 1
                //move view 1 to position 2
            }               
        }
    });
    Delailah.addView(btn);
    parrent.addView(Delailah);
```

Comment: please show piece of code you are using

Answer (score 11):

You can use `ViewGroup.removeView(View)` and [`ViewGroup.addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) for this.

Comment: I got this error after upgraded the kotlin version to 1.5.10 

Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup