# Flip button positions in linear layout vertical

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

well i'm looking for a way to flip the button on a linear layout vertical here is a screen shot of the buttons 
[image]

the xml code is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/buttons_layout">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iv_green"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:src="@drawable/leaf_green"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:onClick="HandleClick" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iv_other"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:src="@drawable/leaf_other"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:onClick="HandleClick" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iv_red"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:src="@drawable/leaf_red"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:onClick="HandleClick" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iv_yellow"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:src="@drawable/leaf_yellow"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:onClick="HandleClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

what i want to do is that when i push flip button on (which is another button) i want to change the position of the current button i will explain in pics:

[image]

okay guys i used the idea that Arnab Told me about in the post below, well i want to randomly flip the image buttons so i did the following script:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
          btnsLayout.removeAllViews();
            ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                a.add(i);
            }

            Collections.shuffle(a);
            btnsLayout.addView(Other, a.get(0).intValue());
            btnsLayout.addView(Green, a.get(1).intValue());
            btnsLayout.addView(Red,a.get(2).intValue());
            btnsLayout.addView(Yellow,a.get(3).intValue());
        }
```

the application is crashing the crash reason is:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=2 count=1 
what does it means ?
Thank you !

Comment: change the order of `ImageButton` in xml layout as its in `LinearLayout` & orientation is vertical so keep it in same order which you want as a output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this inside onCLick(View view) of Flip Button:

```
// Get all the views
LinearLayout btnsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttons_layout);
ImageButton ivGreen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iv_green);
ImageButton ivOther = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iv_other);
ImageButton ivRed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iv_red);
ImageButton ivYellow = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iv_yellow);

// Remove views
btnLayout.removeView(ivGreen);
btnLayout.removeView(ivRed);

// ReAdd views in new index[Index 0 = position 1, Index 2 = position 3]
btnLayout.addView(ivRed, 0);
btnLayout.addView(ivGreen, 2);
```

Similarly :

```
// Remove views
btnLayout.removeView(ivOther);
btnLayout.removeView(ivYellow);

// ReAdd views in new index[Index 1 = position 2, Index 3 = position 4]
btnLayout.addView(ivYellow, 1);
btnLayout.addView(ivOther, 3);
```

Comment: Hello Arnab, if i add all the views in the same groupview and change the index, it will change the button location each time ?

Comment: There's nothing such as groupView. If you mean to say that all Image Views are in same LinearLayout than yes it will work every time. You just need to remove current view and add it to new index.

Comment: @Z. Kiwan(@z-kiwan) if my answer helped you than please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `imgButton.setBackgroundResource();` method.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           imgButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image3);
           imgButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);

        }
    });
```

---

If you want to swap the views you need to use a ViewGroup and you can set the index accordingly.

[How do I change the position of a view in a Linear Layout.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504531/how-do-i-change-the-position-of-a-view-in-a-linear-layout)

Comment: Hello Uma, Thanks for the Reply i don't want to change the Background of the imageview from one button to another. i tried your idea, i want to change the whole button from this position to the other, i don't know if you got my idea :), thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, you should rename the ids of the ImageButtons like :

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/first_leaf"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:src="@drawable/leaf_green"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:onClick="HandleClick" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/second_leaf"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:src="@drawable/leaf_other"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:onClick="HandleClick" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/third_leaf"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
   .../>
```

Then find your flip button in your java class and set an `OnClickListener`
like this:

```
myFlipButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}):
```

Then, in the `onClick` function, perform the changes:

```
myFlipButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         myFirstLeaf.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.leaf_red));
         mySecondLeaf.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.leaf_yellow));
         ...
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Nicolas, the script you suggested change the image of the button but not the properties, i need to change everything, thank you.

Comment: @Z.Kiwan Ok, I thought you wanted to change only the images, not all the properties.

Comment: Changing the image only did the stuff, but it wont change the id which will corrupt the button function.

Comment: @Z.Kiwan You don't have to change the ids, I sait this because after the image changes the ids won't be what they sait ther are. For example iv_green will be the red one. But you can keep your ids like this, there's no probmel with it.

Comment: then the IV_green will make the function of iv_red button but its supposed to make iv_green i don't know if you got the idea

Comment: @Z.Kiwan, OK, I got it ! Well, don't know how to perform it the way you want but you can reset the functions of the images on each changes of the flip button...

Answer (score 0):

Hello Using Arnab Suggestion and some tuning i found a solution: the problem was that you need to insert the index 1 2 3 4 you can't randomly add the views to the linear layout.

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    Button flip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_flip);
    final LinearLayout btnsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttons_layout);
    final ImageView Other = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_other);
    final ImageView Green = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_green);
    final ImageView Red = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_red);
    final ImageView Yellow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_yellow);
    flip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnsLayout.removeAllViews();
            ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                a.add(i);
            }

            Collections.shuffle(a);
            for (int k = 0; k<=3 ; k++){
                if (a.get(0).intValue() == k) {
                    btnsLayout.addView(Other, a.get(0).intValue());
                }
                if (a.get(1).intValue() == k) {
                    btnsLayout.addView(Green, a.get(1).intValue());
                }
                if (a.get(2).intValue() == k) {
                    btnsLayout.addView(Red, a.get(2).intValue());
                }
                if (a.get(3).intValue() == k) {
                    btnsLayout.addView(Yellow, a.get(3).intValue());
                }
            }
        }
```