# How to set Neutral button position to center instead of to the left side in Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Below is my code which shows **ok** **button** to the left side.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("No product found");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setNeutralButton(
                "Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).fragment_Scan_call();
                    }
                });
// Must call show() prior to fetching text view
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Comment: Create a custiom AlertDialog view.

Answer (score 4):

After many Google searching and the studying default AlertDialog layout, I have figured out that there is a space layout between the `neutral button` and `-ve/+ve buttons` with the place "1" in the `buttonBarLayout` in which the buttons.

So, at first, we need to remove that space and or make it's visibility `GONE` (`invisible` will let it still takes a space in the `buttonBarLayout`) also we better to use method onShowListner better than doing that after showing the dialog by:

```
 alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button neutralButton = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) neutralButtonOrAnyOtherBtnFromThe3Btns.getParent();
            Space space= (Space) view.getChildAt(1);
            space.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
 });
```

Then you can desgin buttoms as you want or if you want just to get the space before the nutral buttom you can use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504531/how-do-i-change-the-position-of-a-view-in-a-linear-layout)

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setMessage("No product found");
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setNeutralButton(
            "Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).fragment_Scan_call();
                }
            });
// Must call show() prior to fetching text view
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

final Button neutralButton = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams neutralButtonLL = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) neutralButton.getLayoutParams();
neutralButtonLL.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
neutralButton.setLayoutParams(neutralButtonLL);
```

Comment: Have you tried it ? because for me is not working. In fact, no change in **OK BUTTON** position when try to change(for testing)  **Gravity.CENTER** to HORIZONTAL OR VERTICAL.

Comment: are you setting the layoutParams after calling alert.show()?

Comment: yes, I am setting LayoutParameters after calling alert.show().

Comment: this doesn't works as it changes gravity no layout_gravity

Answer (score 0):

`BUTTON_NEUTRAL`, `BUTTON_NEGATIVE`, and `BUTTON_POSITIVE` don't have any semantics attached to them (apart from the actual names), therefore if you want to 'move' the button positions simply flip your event listeners and labels to whichever button is in the position you want.

I.e. given that your original code was:

```
builder.setNeutralButton("Save Draft", saveDraftListener)
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", cancelListener)
builder.setPositiveButton("Send", sendListener)
```

you can flip it to:

```
// flip neutral and negative buttons
builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", cancelListener)
builder.setNegativeButton("Save Draft", saveDraftListener)
builder.setPositiveButton("Send", sendListener)
```

In the true Humpty-Dumpty way any button can be used for whatever you want, including using `BUTTON_NEGATIVE` as **Ok**, and `BUTTON_POSITIVE` as **Cancel**.